# __weak reference is still a mystery for me

Tags: objective-c

```
 NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"string1"];
__weak NSString *myString1 = myString;
myString= nil;
NSLog(@"%@, %@",myString,myString1);
```

I was expecting `null , null`. But the output is `string1, (null)`. Why is myString1 still holding the value as myString is set to nil?

Comment: This question is not about Xcode nor iPhone. It's a question about Objective-C.

Comment: For me, the output is `(null), string1`.

Comment: It probably won't zero the weak ref until later (exiting the block, etc)

Comment: Don't feel bad -- I'm not sure anyone really understands it (though many pretend to).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Weak references only get zeroed when the object is deallocated. That object is not immediately deallocated (it's probably in an autorelease pool here, though there are many other reasons something might be held onto in different situations), so the reference stays alive.

Comment: This must be the answer. In non-ARC land, `[NSString stringWithFormat]` returns an autoreleased object, so presumably ARC codes it that way too. If instead we do `NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"string1"];` we get the nil output the questioner expects.

Comment: @SteveWaddicor Sort of;  the order of deallocation or the time of deallocation is not necessarily guaranteed.  In fact, turning on the optimizer will likely make things deallocate more quickly (because the optimizer will eliminate what are effectively `retain/autorelease` sequences).

Comment: Thanks for answering this. i was expecting the same.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
NSString *myString;
NSString* __weak myString1;
@autoreleasepool{
    myString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"string1"];
    myString1= myString;
    myString= nil;
}
NSLog(@"%@, %@",myString,myString1);
```

**Explanation**

You probably noticed that there are many methods to allocate a string or generally an object:

1) *[NSString stringWithFormat: ...]* / *[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: ...]* ;
2) *[NSArray arrayWithArray: ...]* / *[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray: ...]*;
...

(Also for many other classes)

The first category of methods return an autoreleased object. The second one a non autoreleased object. Indeed if in the above code you use *alloc* + *initWithFormat:* instead of *stringWithFormat:* you don't need an autorelease pool to see that both objects will be *nil*.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question may be answered by this quote from the [Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW13)

> In particular, *you should not design classes so that dealloc will be
>   invoked when you think it will be invoked*. Invocation of dealloc might
>   be delayed or sidestepped, either because of a bug or because of
>   application tear-down.

Answer (score 0):

The output should be `(null), string1`, not `string1, (null)`. I guess you typed it the wrong way around.

You're explicitly setting one reference to nil, but the other reference is still being used within the scope of the definition (because you're using it in the `NSLog`). So, it won't be released by ARC until that usage is complete.

---

The weak reference isn't holding onto it. The fact that you're using it means that ARC will hold onto it (by not adding the release code). Once that usage is complete, ARC will release the object and then the weak reference will be nilled.

Comment: But surely the point of __weak rather than __strong is that it WON'T hold on to the thing being pointed to.

Comment: It's simply the expected autorelease behaviour of [NSString stringWithFormat]. See Chuck's answer and my comment below it.